ESP8266 NodeMCU SD Card Not Initializing
I have tried numerous tutorials, Arduino examples and I cant get an SD to initialize. There is a card inserted that is formatted with exFAT and there is one file test.txt. Particularly https://www.instructables.com/SD-Card-Module-With-ESP8266/ and https://pawitp.medium.com/esp8266-nodemcu-and-sd-cards-55e0d073d959.
I'm using this SD card module https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0989SM146?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_product_details&th=1. I soldiered the pin connector to the SD card so it would easily set in the breadboard.
Here are a few pics of my breadboard setup:



void SDsetup()
{
pinMode(10, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(10, HIGH);

File Textfile;
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Initializing SD card");

if (!SD.begin(15)) {  
    Serial.println("Initialization failed!");  
    return;
}

Serial.println("Initialization completed"); 
Textfile = SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);  

if (Textfile) {
    Serial.println("Writing to Textfile...");  
    Textfile.println("First line");    
    Textfile.println("1, 2, 3, 4, 5");
    Textfile.println("a, b, c, d, e");
    Textfile.println();
    Textfile.close();     
    Serial.println("Completed");       
    Serial.println();
}
else {
    Serial.println("Text file could not be read");  
}

// READ TEXTFILE
Textfile = SD.open("test.txt");      
if (Textfile) {
    Serial.println("test.txt:");    
    while (Textfile.available()) {
    Serial.write(Textfile.read());     
    }
    Textfile.close();    
}
else  {
    Serial.println("Text file could not be opened"); 
}
//     printDirectory();
//     Serial.println("SDsetup");

//   Serial.print("initializing SD card...");

//   //inicializa o objeto para comunicarmos com o sensor DHT
//   dht.begin();
//   Serial.println("1");

//   // verifica se o cartão SD está presente e se pode ser inicializado
//   if (!SD.begin(4)) {
//     // Serial.print("2");
 //     Serial.println("failed");

//     //programa encerrrado
//     return;
//   }

//   //se chegou aqui é porque o cartão foi inicializado corretamente  
//   Serial.println("card initialized");

}

I forgot to add the serial output:

smart setup
Initializing SD card
Initialization failed!
smart loop

EDIT
I was about to make a new issue on Arduino and ESP8226 githubs but I found this https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem.html#file-system-object-spiffs-littlefs-sd-sdfs and surprisingly SPIFFS sort of worked. It initialized but had problems with read/write.
File Textfile;
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("Initializing SD card");

if (SPIFFS.begin()) {
    Serial.println("Siffs success");
    Textfile = SPIFFS.open("test.txt", "w");
    if (Textfile) {
        Serial.write(Textfile.read());
        Serial.println("Writing to Textfile...");
        Textfile.println("First line");
        Textfile.println("1, 2, 3, 4, 5");
        Textfile.println("a, b, c, d, e");
        Textfile.println();
        Textfile.close();
        Serial.println("Completed");
        Serial.println();
        Serial.write(Textfile.read());
    }
}
else {
    Serial.println("Text file could not be read");
}
if (!SD.begin(15)) {
    Serial.println("Initialization failed!");
    return;
}

The above code produced the below log:

Initializing SD card
Siffs success
�Writing to Textfile...
Completed

�Initialization failed!


how do you know that the SD card is not initializing?... please copy and paste the entire content of the serial monitor into your post ... format as code for readability... no screenshots ... do not write a comment

Do you even know if the file system code supports exFAT? Have you debugged where the code fails and for what reason?

I read in one of the tutorials that ESP8226 only supports FAT. FAT32 is no longer an option when formatting now in Windows. My only options were exFAT or NTFS. I would think it would work since its still FAT.

You may want to look into the official sdcard.org memory card formatter before troubleshooting the hardware further

I will check it out.
